# Java string parsing to HashMap

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have an input string of the following format:

Message:id1:[label1:label2....:labelN]:id2:[label1:label2....:labelM]:id3:[label1:label2....:labelK]...

It is basically ids associated with sets of labels. There can be an arbitrary number of ids and labels associated with those ids.

I want to be able to parse this string and generate a HashMap of the form id->labels for quick look up later.

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of parsing this message in java?

Comment: A series of `String#split()` should do the trick.

Comment: That looks a lot like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
String str = "Message:id1:[label1:label2:labelN]:id2:[label1:label2:labelM]:id3:[label1:label2:labelK]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:]+):\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str.substring(8));
Map<String, List<String>> idmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 
while (m.find()) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] tok = m.group(2).split(":");
    for (String t: tok)
        l.add(t);
    idmap.put(m.group(1), l);
}
System.out.printf("IdMap %s%n", idmap);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/EoieUt

Comment: That is simply awesome. I couldn't come up with a regexp for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

If you take the string you gave:

```
Message:id1:[label1:label2....:labelN]:id2:[label1:label2....:labelM]:id3:[label1:label2....:labelK]
```

And do `String.split("]")`, You get:

```
Message:id1:[label1:label2....:labelN
:id2:[label1:label2....:labelM
:id3:[label1:label2....:labelK
```

If you loop through each of those, splitting on `[`, you get:

```
Message:id1:     label1:label2....:labelN
:id2:            label1:label2....:labelM
:id3:            label1:label2....:labelK
```

Then, you can parse the `id` name out of the first element in the `String[]`, and the labelname out of the second element in the `String`, and store that in your `Multimap`.

If you don't want to use Guava, you can also use a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

Following code will serve your requirement.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RegexTest {

        public static void main(String[] args){
           String msg = "id1:[label1:label2]:id2:[label1:label2:label3]:id3:[label1:label2:label3:label4]";
           Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("id");
            HashMap<String,String> kv = new HashMap<String,String>();
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(msg);

            int prev = -1;
            int next = -1;
            int start = -1;
            int end = -1;

            String subMsg = "";
            while (m.find()){
                if(prev == -1){
                    prev = m.end();
                }
                else
                {
                    next = m.end();
                    start = prev;
                    end =   next;
                    subMsg = msg.substring(start,end);
                    kv.put(String.valueOf(subMsg.charAt(0)),subMsg.substring(subMsg.indexOf("["),subMsg.lastIndexOf("]")+1));
                    prev = next;
                }
            }
            subMsg = msg.substring(next);
            kv.put(String.valueOf(subMsg.charAt(0)),subMsg.substring(subMsg.indexOf("["),subMsg.lastIndexOf("]")+1));

            System.out.println(kv);
        }
}
```

Output : {3=[label1:label2:label3:label4], 2=[label1:label2:label3], 1=[label1:label2]}

Live Demo : http://ideone.com/HM7989